# radianpersecond error in SIUNITX

Tags: siunitx

Simply, radianpersecond doesn't work; all other units does.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a&=\SI{1}{cm}\\
\omega&=\SI{1}{\radianpersecond}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \end{align}
```

I don't understand why only this unit doesn't work!

Comment: This means that `\radianpersecond` is not defined! Shouldn't it be `\radian\per\second`?

Comment: OK Thanks that works, the thing is that TeXStudio gave me that option: \radianpersecond so I thought that's the one!

Comment: Well, that's TeXStudio's fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package doesn't define `\radianpersecond`. Either you type

```
\SI{1}{\radian\per\second}
```

or add, in the preamble,

```
\DeclareSIUnit\radianpersecond{\radian\per\second}
```

and then you'll be allowed to type also

```
\SI{1}{\radianpersecond}
```

Note: it seems a bug in TeXStudio if its palettes suggest `\radianpersecond` as an existing unit.

Comment: Even though you could, I would recommend not creating a macro for that (not saying that you are).  You save two backslash keystrokes and you make your code less portable.